# Capybara: Pulling in multiple Radio button options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Im running into an issue, and I think the issue is with how my page.all is pulling radio button questions in.

So here is the HTML for the table itself (Multiple questions with 5 radio button choices a piece):

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-stuff table-collapsible">
    <colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <input id="0_answer_question_id" value="9966" name="response[answers][0][answer_id]" type="hidden">
    <tr>
    <td class="heading">
    <td class="option">
    <div class="radio-inline radio-inline--empty">
    <input id="question_1_1" value="1" name="response[answers_attributes][0][answer_opinion]" type="radio">
    <label for="question_1_1">Strongly Disagree</label>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="option">
    <td class="option">
    <td class="option">
    <td class="option">
    </tr>
    <input id="response_1_question_id" value="9966" name="response[answers_attributes][1][answer_question_id]" type="hidden">
    <tr>
    <input id="response_1_id" value="<a number>" name="response[answers_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden">
   <Same as above repeated 5 times with numbers changed>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Im using:

```
page.all('table.table-stuff tbody tr', minimum: 6).each do |row|
  row.all("td label").sample.trigger('click')
end
```

To get each row and select one from it. HOWEVER, I notice "sometimes" a row will not have one selected. My theory is the "heading" (which has a <label> itself is accepting one of the clicks perhaps? (since from my understanding of how page.all works it's grabbing every `tbody tr` within the table...but is maybe grabbing the heading too? (since it contains a `td label`?)

Also when a table is named something like `table table-striped table-stuff table-collapsible`...how can you tell what the actual table "name" is? (I didn't write this website, just doing tests for it). When putting it in the `page.all('table.<etc>')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the heading td (it's not expanded in your example) also contains a label element (so it would be included in the results of your `all` call) then you just need to change the CSS selector so it wouldn't be included - something like

```
row.all("td.option label").sample.trigger('click') # only choose labels contined in tds with the class of 'option'
```

or

```
row.all("td:not(.heading) label").sample.trigger('click') # choose labels contained in tds without the class of 'heading'
```

On your second question about table names, I don't really understand what you're asking.  Tables don't have name attributes, they could have an id attribute or a caption containing some text which could then be used to find them with capybara via `find(:table, 'id or caption text')` or `within_table('id or caption text') {  code to execute within scope of the table }`. Rather, you seem to be talking about the classes on the element which are specified in a CSS selector with '.'.  Therefore a CSS selector to match a table element with all the classes you listed would be - 'table.table.table-striped.table-stuff.table-collapsible'

Note: If you're sure there's always only 5 choices you could add the :count option to your find to make sure your selector is only finding those items

```
row.all("td.option label", count: 5).sample.trigger('click')
```

Comment: This ended up working, because in fact the heading did have a label option. (At least im learning WHY things aren't working haha). Your table answer did answer my question, looks like they are just multiple classes.